# Learning/applying jQuery before JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

NOTE: I am not in any way asking whether or not I should learn JavaScript before jQuery. I understand that jQuery is simply a framework for JavaScript and as such JavaScript should be learned first.

I currently know HTML and CSS and I'm looking to expand into JavaScript. I have used several resources from tuts+ to treehouse to learn HTML and CSS, but recently I stumbled across a website called code school that I really enjoy using.

When I go to their JavaScript section, it appears they skip JavaScript all together and jump right into jQuery. My question is - should I learn JavaScript on some other website before learning jQuery on code school? Or do you think it's a good idea to just learn jQuery right out of the gate like they basically force you to do on their site?

Comment: <<I am not in any way asking whether or not I should learn JavaScript before jQuery>> <<My question is - should I learn JavaScript on some other website before learning jQuery>> ???

Comment: It is *never* a good idea to write code you don't understand.  And if you don't know JavaScript, you won't understand how jQuery works -- or more importantly, *doesn't* work, in those cases where it can't do everything for you.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I'd suggest learning JavaScript and the DOM API, and building a solid foundation. You'll discover that for many projects you'll not need jQuery at all. With browser compatibility rapidly improving, there's much less point to a monolithic abstraction like jQuery.

Comment: This kind of question doesn't really belong here because there is no real answer, just opinions.  It really depends on how they teach you at Code School, jQuery is powerful and useful, but sometimes people have a tendency to use it for everything, when that isn't what it is for.

Comment: @roasted I had a good laugh about that too :)

Comment: JavaScript is a programming language.  jQuery is a library.  You need to learn JavaScript first, so that you know how to use the language.  Then you can learn the library that uses it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the answers here... you learn things by doing, and you do things with examples. It's not the end of the world if you start off just playing around with examples from the website that you don't fully understand. Of course, if you get serious about it, you'll have to read the more advanced stuff eventually. As user2532739 says, this is all just opinions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is just a Javascript library. You can't use jQuery without knowing Javascript.

However, by following jQuery tutorials, you may be able to pick up enough Javascript to get along. But if this is the first procedural language you're using, you may also get very confused.

Answer (score 0):

NetTuts, as good as it is for exposing a variety of different frameworks, is not a great place to learn jQuery or JavaScript. I would recommend getting your hands on some books referenced here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript